How long did the 19th century Europe Grand Tour take?
I’m writing a story set it 1815 and I want it to be as close as possible to history.
I know the countries that were visited and the routes they took, but I will love to know how much time it took between stops.
For example, from London port to France port, they had to take a boat to cross, how long was the boat ride?  I know they traveled by carriages or horse backs, but how much time was the travel by carriage from the port of France, where they docked, to Paris? And then to Geneva? So on.
My goal is for the main character to arrive to Athens traveling all the way from London without stopping, since they are running away from everything. And for me the time lapse it’s important.
Also it will help me to know how much time it took for letters to arrive in such distance.

If you click on the [travel] tag I have added, you will find some similar questions and answers that may help.

@Ale It might be faster for them to sail from Marsailles or Venice to Athens.  And whethr by land and/or sea they would have to travel from country to country, from the UK to the Ottoman Empire, which might involve paperwork at border crossings or ports.

"London port to France port" - depends on the weather.

Which part of 1815? Napoleon's Hundred Days might complicate travel plans a little...

If your character is "traveling all the way from London without stopping", why not just get a ship from London to Athens?

The length of a Channel crossing in a sailing ship would be totally dependent on the weather. (BTW Are you writing it in English? There are many errors in your post - "I know the countries that were visited...")

I would recommend you to read a few relevant books.

@KateBunting English is not my first language and it was kind of late when o wrote the post. But thanks for point it out so I can be more careful.

@KillingTime And how much time would that trip take? I couldn’t find information of boat trips going from London to Greece.

The 'Grand Tour' was not a hurried journey to a particular city, but a leisurely tour of Europe taken by wealthy young men as part of their 'education', visiting various places of historic or cultural interest. People travelling by sea would probably have to apply to be passengers in a naval or merchant ship that was going to the required destination - and, as I said, all sea journeys were weather-dependent.

@LarsBosteen: In particular, note that Wellington's dispatch to London after Waterloo was delayed due to being becalmed between Ostend and Dover.
